# jQuery getJSON sortable callback

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jquery-ui-sortable, getjson

I am going through a tutorial to implement a sortable list and I can't tell if the json is being loaded or not. Is there a way with Firebug and Firequery to see if it's getting called or if it's a bad address? There are no errors that I can see. My html along with Coldfusion :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$sortable = $("#sortable").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui){
    updateOrder();
  }
}).disableSelection();


function updateOrder(){  
  $.getJSON(
    'remote.cfc?wsdl',
    { 
      method : 'updateOrder', 
      key: '<cfoutput>#session.ajaxkey#</cfoutput>',
      orderedList: $sortable.sortable('toArray').toString(),
      returnformat: 'json', 
      queryformat: 'column',          
    },
    callback
  );
}
});

function callback(json){
if ( json.RESULT )
{
  $('#serverresult').text( "Order updated to: " + json.NEWORDER );
}
else
{
  $('#serverresult').text( "Something went wrong!" );
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<body>
<h1>Menu List</h1>

       <cfquery name="rsSort" datasource="#DataSource#">
SELECT * FROM `test-sort` ORDER by Sort 
</cfquery>

<div class="demo">
<ul id="sortable">
<cfoutput>
<cfloop query="rsSort">
<li id="id_#ID#">#Title# #ID#</li>

</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
</ul>
<div id="serverresult">
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

file that's getting called:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" hint="I respond to AJAX requests">


<cffunction name="updateOrder" output="false" access="remote">
<cfargument name="orderedList" required="true" type="string">
<cfargument name="key" required="true" type="string">

<cfset var ndx = "">
<cfset var id = 0>
<cfset var position = 0>
<cfset var updatedids = "">
<cfset var result = {result="false"}>

<!--- do a basic security check --->
<cfif isAllowed( arguments.key )>

  <!--- Prevent race conditions --->
  <cflock name="updateOrder" timeout="60">
    <cftransaction>
      <cfloop list="#arguments.orderedList#" index="ndx">

        <cfset id = Val( ListLast( ndx, "_" ) )>
        <cfset position = position+1>
        <cfset updatedids = ListAppend( updatedids, id )>

        <cfquery datasource="#DataSource#">
          update `test-sort` set
            Sort = <cfqueryparam value="#position#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
          where 
          id = <cfqueryparam value="#id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        </cfquery>

      </cfloop>

      <!--- delete any items not in the list --->
      <cfquery datasource="#DataSource#">
        delete from `test-sort`
        where id not in ( <cfqueryparam value="#updatedids#"  cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true"> )
      </cfquery>

    </cftransaction>
  </cflock>

  <cfset result = {result="true", neworder=updatedids, position=position }>

</cfif>

<cfreturn result>
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="isAllowed" output="false" access="private" returntype="boolean">
<cfargument name="key" required="true">
<cfset var result = false>
<!--- check that request is coming from the same browser that created the session --->
<cfif IsDefined( "session.ajaxkey" ) AND ( session.ajaxkey eq arguments.key )>
  <cfset result = true>
</cfif>
<cfreturn result>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: you can look at ajax requests in several places in Firebug. Simplest place for me is enabling `showXMLHttpRequests` in console tab. Another place is in `Net` tab. Will see status, data sent, response returned, headers etc by expanding the request itself. Will even create a JSON tree if dataType is JSON

Comment: Thanks! I was able to see it in Firefox finally and saw that it wasn't recognizing the datasource variable

Comment: my coldfusion is rusty but seems like you are missing `<cfoutput>`

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly don't want the ?wsdl in the URL you're ajaxing to. That'll just return you the WSDL XML for your CFC. Hopefully Firebug will show that up. You can also use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to debug network traffic (works on all browsers)

You may also need to set returnformat="JSON" in your cffunction in order to get CF to turn the struct you are returning into JSON.

Comment: Thanks @barnyr I'm going to remove ?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Using `?wsdl` works for me ok, I think your first line in your callback should be:

`var JSON=jQuery.parseJSON(json);`

Then use JSON instead of json in this function.